# URL Rewrite for multiple pages but same query

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

As of now I have one generic query "view" which I'll use on most pages...

My rewrite is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ $1.php?view=$2 [L]
```

My url is:

> classroom.php?view=creation

I want it to look like:

> classroom/creation

I have it working but it screwed up other urls

> dashboard.php was just /dashboard

but broke when I did the first rewrite rule...

These things are a pain to understand.

My Question is how can i have /dashboard, /classroom, /classroom/creation work?

EDIT: I got it working with:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$  $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ $1.php?view=$2 [L]
```

Comment: What is the question ? Do you use mod_rewrite? Show your rules.

Comment: I edited it to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first 2 rules are for external redirect, which turns `.php` into a directory like format rest of the rules are for the internal redirect which keeps the pretty URL and doesn't show the redirect.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect /classroom.php?view=creation to /classroom/creation
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+classroom\.php\?view=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /classroom/%1? [R=302,L]

# Redirect /classroom.php to /classroom and /dashboard.php to /dashboard
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(classroom|dashboard)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L]

# Internally forward /classroom/creation to /classroom.php?view=creation
RewriteRule ^classroom/(.*)/?$ /classroom.php?view=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Internally forward /classroom to /classroom.php and /dashboard to /dashboard.php
RewriteRule ^(classroom|dashboard)/?$ /$1.php [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Is there a reason to do it like you died compared to my most recent edit? I'm accomplishing the same thing in 2 lines aren't i?

Comment: @Dom if you do yourdomain.com/classroom.php you will still access the php file, what you are currently doing is simple redirecting pretty URL to the file internally but not the file itself to the pretty URL.

Comment: Very interesting. So does this mean that huge sites out there have their .ht_access littered with different rules? There is no way to globally make it?

Comment: You mean globally redirect php to a folder like scheme with a single rule ? I don't think so. You need 1 to redirect and another to receive otherwise you would fall a infinite loop. Your rule is not wrong it will just not redirect the php to the directory like style you can even hide that you are using php using htaccess and a lot of other cool things for example you can make your php file look like an asp page or make a custom extension let's say you have a company called yellowsubmarine you can make your files like index.yellowsubmarine which is actually php files masked with that extension.